# Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions

Tags: react-native, babeljs, flowtype, babel-preset-env

I'm getting this error after updating react-native to `"^0.56.0"`:

```
 bundling failed: Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/ben/vepo/frontend/node_modules/babel-preset-flow/lib/index.js
```

I tried to do something similar to the highest voted answer here but instead for babel-preset-flow:

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/issues/540

.babelrc:

```
"presets": ["react-native", "flow", "@babel/preset-flow"]
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "vepo",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./app/fonts"
    ]
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0-beta.52",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.52",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "^4.0.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.4.0",
    "generator-rn-toolbox": "^2.2.0",
    "imagemagick": "^0.1.3",
    "immutable": "4.0.0-rc.9",
    "metro-bundler": "^0.22.1",
    "native-base": "^2.3.3",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "^0.56.0",
    "react-native-aws3": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-blur": "^3.1.3",
    "react-native-communications": "^2.2.1",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-fbsdk": "facebook/react-native-fbsdk#065507a",
    "react-native-git-upgrade": "^0.2.7",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.26.7",
    "react-native-interactable": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-mail": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.16.4",
    "react-native-modal": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-modalbox": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-multiple-choice": "^0.0.8",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.100",
    "react-native-off-canvas-menu": "^0.1.31",
    "react-native-optimized-flatlist": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-redux-router": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-select-multiple": "^1.0.3",
    "react-native-side-menu": "^0.20.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.4.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-immutable": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-observable": "^0.14.1",
    "reselect": "^3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.2.0",
    "yarn": "^1.3.2",
    "yoga": "^0.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "adm-zip": "^0.4.7",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^2.7.0",
    "eslint": "^3.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.30.3",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx": "^0.0.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.10.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^2.3.1",
    "flow-bin": "^0.72.0",
    "plist": "^2.1.0",
    "react-devtools": "^3.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "~15.4.1",
    "redux-devtools": "^3.3.2",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.7",
    "remotedev-server": "^0.2.4",
    "xcode": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Nothing is working. Any ideas?

EDIT: there is no node_modules/babel-preset-flow folder at all

Comment: Could you resolve this?, i've the same error :(

Comment: @Guille No I couldn't fix this error so I reverted back to react-native version 0.55.4 which doesn't have the error for me.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same error and resolved it by uninstalling `babel-preset-flow` and installing `@babel/preset-flow`. I believe this is due to React Native 56 using Babel 7. And add to `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["@babel/preset-flow"]
}
```

Comment: thanks this solved my problem as well, upvote for saving me time!

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem too. Try to follow this doc https://flow.org/en/docs/react/

Comment: I'm getting  == Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-flow' from <project path>
- Did you mean "@babel/flow"?

Answer (score 11):

Upgrade your babel-preset-react-native dependency.

```
"babel-preset-react-native": "^5",
```

You don't need to have `@babel/preset-react` or `@babel/preset-flow` installed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: didn't solve my problem :s I am using detox and still getting the same error with this and react `0.55.4`

Answer (score 8):

Open `.babelrc` file and then edit the presets section of the code as follows:

```
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
```

Comment: after this, I had another problem, which is solved there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51765313/react-native-v0-56-cannot-read-property-filename-of-undefined-at-pluginpass-j/51772754 , then it started to work

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue by installing `"babel-preset-react-native-stage-0"` in my project and changed `.babelrc` file:

```
"presets": [
    "babel-preset-react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
  ]
```

Answer (score 0):

for Babel 7 and above and according to [this document](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/usage#overview) create a file with name `bable.config.js` instead of `.babelrc` and then export presets like this :

```
const presets = [
    "flow"
]

module.exports = {presets}
```